# How to instantiate a Scikit-Learn linear model with known coefficients without fitting it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, initialization, linear-regression

**Background**

I am testing various saved models as part of an experiment, but one of the models comes from an algorithm I wrote, not from a sklearn model-fitting.

However, my custom model is still a linear model so I want to instantiate a `LinearModel` instance and set the `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes to the values from my custom fitting algorithm so I can use it for predictions.

**What I tried so far:**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

my_intercepts = np.ones(2)
my_coefficients = np.random.randn(2, 3)

new_model = LinearRegression()
new_model.intercept_ = my_intercepts
new_model.coef_ = my_coefficients
```

It seems to work okay for prediction:

```
X_test = np.random.randn(5, 3)

new_model.predict(X_test)
```

It passes this test:

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted

check_is_fitted(new_model)
```

**Question**

Is this method fine?  It feels like a hack and I suspect there is a 'proper' way to do this.

Comment: Not sure there is any "proper" way to do this, in the sense that I highly doubt that such a usage was even remotely present in the minds of the people who built scikit-learn, but since it passes the tests and does not give error with `.predict`, I can't see any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the simple technique in the question works, the danger is that you might later call the object's fit method and over-write your coefficients.

A slightly more 'proper' way to do this, if the model is only going to be used for prediction, would be to inherit from sklearn's class and overload the fit method as follows:

```
class LinearPredictionModel(LinearRegression):
    """
    This model is for prediction only.  It has no fit method.
    You can initialize it with fixed values for coefficients 
    and intercepts.  

    Parameters
    ----------
    coef, intercept : arrays
        See attribute descriptions below.

    Attributes
    ----------
    coef_ : array of shape (n_features, ) or (n_targets, n_features)
        Coefficients of the linear model.  If there are multiple targets
        (y 2D), this is a 2D array of shape (n_targets, n_features), 
        whereas if there is only one target, this is a 1D array of 
        length n_features.
    intercept_ : float or array of shape of (n_targets,)
        Independent term in the linear model.
    """

    def __init__(self, coef=None, intercept=None):
        if coef is not None:
            coef = np.array(coef)
            if intercept is None:
                intercept = np.zeros(coef.shape[0])
            else:
                intercept = np.array(intercept)
            assert coef.shape[0] == intercept.shape[0]
        else:
            if intercept is not None:
                raise ValueError("Provide coef only or both coef and intercept")
        self.intercept_ = intercept
        self.coef_ = coef

    def fit(self, X, y):
        """This model does not have a fit method."""
        raise NotImplementedError("model is only for prediction")
```

Then, instantiate the model as follows:

```
new_model = LinearPredictionModel(coef=my_coefficients, intercept=my_intercepts)
```

I think the only 'proper' way to do this would be for me to fully implement a new class with my custom algorithm in the fit method.  But for the simple needs of testing the coefficients in a scikit-learn environment, this method seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works nicely for primitive methods (such as linear-regression), but how can you tweak this for more complex models (such as lasso or elastic net or...). It appears the linear regressor can be modified like this, but a lasso regressor still throws errors (complaint of not being fit: [As in this question, which is indicated as a duplicate of the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748510/how-to-create-a-scikit-learn-model-using-user-selected-model-parameters?noredirect=1#comment109222897_61748510).

Comment: Good point.  I did not investigate other types of model.  [In the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html#sklearn-utils-validation-check-is-fitted) it says the `check_is_fitted` method works by "verifying the presence of fitted attributes (ending with a trailing underscore)".  So presumably you need to make sure a value is set for every required attribute.

Comment: @Bill That is interesting to know. I'll look into it myself as well. If it can tell me which attributes are missing, that would help me out a lot.