# Use existing coefficient and intercept in Linear regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression

I'm using `scikit-learn` module for `Linear Regression`. My model runs every day, now i store the model's variable (coef_ & intercept_) to file, so that it can be used again when my model run.

Let's suppose, on a history of one year, i'm running the model daily. On 25th of November, i saved the model's `coef_` & `intercept_` in a file, so again i restart my program, and it will start from 25th of November, and run till the last

So when i compare the predictions for 26th November before and after the restarting, predictions are different. So i just thought of using the `coef_` & `intercept_` before restarting, so that after restart, it should predict the same for 26th November.

To do this, i just overwrite the `coef_` & `intercept_`

```
from sklearn import linear_model

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.coef_ = coef_stored
model.intercept_ = intercept_stored

model.fit(X, y)
model.predict(x)
```

I want my predictions for 26th to be same, before and after the restart. Using above code i was not able to achieve it.

Comment: @desertnaut prediction of same date (26th Nov) is different for before and after the restart. Also writing this in question

Answer (score 1):

Altering the attributes of an untrained model is not recommended, but following desertnaut's comment you can do it as shown in [How to instantiate a Scikit-Learn linear model with known coefficients without fitting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491678/how-to-instantiate-a-scikit-learn-linear-model-with-known-coefficients-without-f).

However, if you call the `fit` method, then the coefficient and intercept will be **overwritten**.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

my_intercepts = np.ones(2)
my_coefficients = np.random.randn(2, 3)

new_model = LinearRegression()
new_model.intercept_ = my_intercepts
new_model.coef_ = my_coefficients

print(new_model.coef_)
#[[ 1.76405235  0.40015721  0.97873798]
# [ 2.2408932   1.86755799 -0.97727788]]


new_model.predict(np.random.randn(5, 3))
#array([[ 2.51441481,  2.94725181],
#       [ 3.20531004,  0.76788778],
#       [ 2.82562532,  2.49886169],
#       [ 1.98568931,  4.73850448],
#       [-1.28821286,  2.60145844]])
```

---

You said:

> So i just thought of using the coef_ & intercept_ before restarting,
>   so that after restart, it should predict the same for 26th November.

If you do not get the same results when you are sure that you use the same **data** and **model coefficients**, then something is wrong. Small differences can be expected across `sklearn` versions in case you upgraded `sklearn` between the before and after states of your program.

Comment: Your basic premise here does not hold; it is indeed possible to define `model.coef_` the way OP shows before even fitting the model: [How to instantiate a Scikit-Learn linear model with known coefficients without fitting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491678/how-to-instantiate-a-scikit-learn-linear-model-with-known-coefficients-without-f). Notice that OP has not yet reported any specific error they may have been facing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It's the first time I see that but still super dangerous to do so.

Comment: It was the first time I saw it as well, that's why I bookmarked the thread! I was very surprised that it even worked, but I wouldn't agree that it is dangerous (provided of course that you know exactly what you're doing).

Comment: I agree but you can easily forget that `.fit()` should not been called. In any case, I have tried to also answer the second part of the question.

Comment: That's for sure; as for the rest, I'm not sure yet that OP has expressed exactly what their issue is, especially what exactly constitutes a "restart" here.

Comment: As a consequence of a still not clear question, your answer may look unnecessarily convoluted, too (and the second part possibly irrelevant). It may very well be the case here that the answer is simply "use `predict` before `fit`".